# Pass socket.io room with socket_write?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am curently using `socket_write` to open a websocket and pass data to a node.js socket.io server. I am sending bits of HTML like so:

```
private function openSocketConnection($address = 'localhost', $port = 5600)
{
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

    return $socket;
}

$socket = $this->openSocketConnection();

socket_write($socket, $html, strlen($html));
```

This works perfectly fine and sends my data to my node.js socket.io server where I catch it like so:

`socket.on('data', (msg) => {});`

But I now want to send the data so a specific room instead of the general socket.io room. Is there a way with this setup where I can specify a room?

Perhaps when using `socket_create()` or something? Obviously I would like to prevent to pass the room name on every `socket_write` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients can only send data to the server itself.  If you want to send a message to all users in a specific room, then create a message that the client can send that will tell the server to do that on behalf of the client.

```
// client-side
socket.emit("sendToRoom", {room: "someRoom", data: "Hello"});
```

And, then on the server:

```
socket.on('sendToRoom', function(msg) {
    // send to all clients in the room except the socket client
    socket.broadcast.to(msg.room, msg.data);
});
```

If the client is only in one room, then you can have the client just send a message to broadcast to its current room and have the server look up what room it's in.  That way, the client does not have to send the room every time.

Comment: Client side just needs to receive data. I need a way to communicate from PHP to my server a specific room name though. Would this mean I would have to pass an object containing my HTML and room name for every 'socket_write'?

Comment: @Stephan-v - Did you see my last paragraph?  I am confused because you discuss BOTH a webSocket and socket.io.  Do you have two separate connections?  A socket.io server can lookup what rooms any client is in.

Comment: There is no bridge like Redis or something like that. I am sending data straight from PHP's native websocket functionality to my node.js server. This server just gets generic data but at that point I have lost the ability to tell the node.js server which room to send the data to.

Comment: @Stephan-v -I really don't understand what your problem is.  Like I said, a node.js server KNOWS what rooms a connection is in, so you can just look it up on the node.js server if you're trying to send to the same room that the connection is in.  Other than that, you have to tell the server what room you want the message to go to and the only way to do that for an incoming socket.io message is to include it in the message.  I have no idea what you would be hoping to do with redis.

Comment: `and the only way to do that for an incoming socket.io message is to include it in the message` thank you that was the answer I was looking for. I wanted to know if that was the only option or not.